# GRUB bootloader took over my computer

Tags: bootloader

I have two completely separate drives in my computer. One has Windows7 and that was already installed. I installed Ubuntu on my other drive specifically for Ubuntu, and now GRUB boot-load shows up no matter what order my boot priority is in my BIOS. This never happened before, and They both kept on their own drives. What happened? The only way for me to get into Windows anymore is for GRUB boot-loader to load up and to select the Windows7 loader listed towards the bottom of the list(on a completely separate drive. I want them separate hence the reason I have two separate drives.

I have tried to repair the Windows Boot-Loader with the installation disc, but it does not even show up in the list. I think Ubuntu installed GRUB into the Windows Boot partition maybe?

Also, I have unplugged the Ubuntu drive and re-booted. The Windows 7 will not start. After bios int, computer just sits. What happened?!

Comment: Have you tried the repair disk with the ubuntu drive unplugged? If i'm reading correctly, it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: Post is so failed to mention the exact problem.Separate boot loader for different OS is not possible but you can select from a list of options.But you have to connect both drive during installation.You installed Ubuntu after windows,so the last installed one appear the first on list.By reading your post 15 times,what I understood that everything is clear and done well as normal.

Comment: I used to have ubuntu and windows7 on two separate drive, and whatever order I had them in BIOS boot order, they would boot. Now my Windows7 wont even boot when the ubuntu drive is unplugged. I know it's possible to have the two drives completely separate. I AM USING TWO PHYSICALLY SEPARATE DRIVES! NOT PARTITIONS!

Comment: I am having the same issue. It started happening after I installed Ubuntu behind a Windows 7 installation. My machine has UEFI enabled and I think this has something to do with the problem. I can't even hit F2 to enter the BIOS or boot from a CD/DVD ROM any longer. Sucks!  Ubuntu 12.04... are you using UEFI and Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already had the Windows boot loader on one drive, and when you installed Ubuntu, chose to install grub to the same drive, and never put a boot loader on the second drive.  If you want to put the Windows boot loader back, you need to boot the Windows install cd, go into the recovery console and use the `FIXMBR` command.

Comment: I tried the FIXMBR command from the command line and says no such command.

Comment: You need to do it from the recovery prompt on the Windows Install CD.